# R program, ?count, rename "freq" to something else

Tags: r, count, aggregate

I am studying this [webpage](https://www.miskatonic.org/2012/09/24/counting-and-aggregating-r/), and cannot figure out how to rename `freq` to something else, say `number of times imbibed`

Here is dput

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Bill", "Llib"), class = "factor"), drink = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("cocoa", "coffee", "tea", 
"water"), class = "factor"), cost = 1:8), .Names = c("name", 
"drink", "cost"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is working code with output. Again, I'd like to rename the `freq` column. Thanks!

```
library(plyr)

bevs$cost <- as.integer(bevs$cost)
count(bevs, "name")
```

Output

```
  name freq
1 Bill    4
2 Llib    4
```

Comment: I don't think `count` has this functionality. Just rename it afterwards.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh ok, now I understand. Still very new to R Programming, hence this glaring obvious fact ;-)

Comment: I didn't downvote you btw. I think though, that you should try a bit newer packages for your tasks, not to mention that for that simple task, you could do just `as.data.frame(table(bevs$name))` without loading `plyr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
counts <- count(bevs, "name")
names(counts) <- c("name", "number of times imbibed")
counts
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` function returns a `data.frame`. Just rename it like any other `data.frame`:

```
counts <- count(bevs, "name")
names(counts)[which(names(counts) == "freq")] <- "number of times imbibed"
print(counts)
#   name number of times imbibed
# 1 Bill                       4
# 2 Llib                       4
```